# Implementing a bidirectional listview in Flutter

Tags: widget, scrollview, flutter

How do you implement a bidirectional scroll view in Flutter? ListView has a scrollDirection field however it can only take either Axis.horizontal or Axis.vertical. Is is possible to have both?

Answer (score 7):

Here's a potential solution using an outer `SingleChildScrollView`. You could also use a `PageView` of multiple `ListViews` if you're ok with the offscreen `ListView`s being torn down.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyHomePage(),
  ));
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: new SizedBox(
          width: 1000.0,
          child: new ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
              return new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: new List.generate(5, (int j) {
                  return new Text("$i,$j", style: themeData.textTheme.display2);
                }),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Any thoughts on if it would be possible to scroll on a diagonal? meaning both horizontal and vertical scrolling are performed at the same time?

Comment: Unless you have a lot of content, I think you should probably just use a `GestureDetector` to reposition an element when the user drags, rather than making it scrollable... the main thing that Scrollables provide is bounce physics and overscrow glow when you get to the end... how much do you care about that?

Comment: Oh then it sounds like repositioning elements is really what I need. So my content is gonna go beyond horizontal and vertical limits of the screen. So whichever direction I fling, or drag, I'd like to reposition my items while adding deceleration when the user releases his or her finger for a more natural feel

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44468337/how-can-i-make-a-scrollable-wrapping-view-with-flutter) that I posted and self-answered. I'm not aware of a way to do it with a single `Scrollable`, although I can imagine it being useful.

> You can't easily solve this with an infinite-length `ListView.builder`
>   because it only goes in one direction. If you want to wrap in both
>   directions, it is possible to simulate bidirectional wrapping with a
>   `Stack` of two `Viewport`s going in opposite directions.

There's a code sample on the question too (you might have to modify the answer a bit if you don't want wrapping).

Comment: I have seen that example. However, it only demonstrates infinite scrolling and in one direction: vertical. It doesn't show the case where you can also scroll horizontally as well

Comment: Haha no problem :)