# Adding both vertical and horizontal scrolling to ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make the `Row`s inside a vertical `ListView`, scrollable horizontally.

This is what my app looks like:

[image]

I want the user to be able to scroll the ListView both horizontally (to see the contents of the `Row`) and vertically to see new list items. This behavior is like how you would scroll a `DataTable` in Flutter:

[image]

Here is the build method (based on the Flutter project template):

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final List<String> rows = [
    "This is a row with some very long text ... That goes on and on",
    "This class is the configuration for the state.",
    "case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and",
    "always marked \"final\"."
  ];

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("ListView")),
    body: ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      children: <Widget>[
        for (final String row in rows)
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[Text(row)],
          )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Update: Wrapping the `Text` in `Expanded` doesn't work as it causes the text to wrap onto multiple lines. I want the text to remain on a single line.

Comment: Add a listview as children and use scrollDirection:  Axis.horizontal .

Comment: @Rubens Melo That would only make a single row scrollable, but is there a way to make the whole ListView scrollable?

Answer (score 2):

**Finally**
After a deep search found this finally

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: new SizedBox(
          width: 1000.0,
          child: new ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
              return new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: new List.generate(5, (int j) {
                  return new Text("$i,$j");
                }),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Original source [Vote up his answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137297/implementing-a-bidirectional-listview-in-flutter?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This makes a `Text` row individually scrollable, but I want to be able to scroll the whole `ListView` horizontally, not just a single `Row`.

Comment: @S.D. check my udpate

Comment: Close, but then `Axis.horizontal` prevents vertical scrolling of the `ListView`. I have added a video that shows how you can scroll both vertical and horizontally in what I'm trying to create.

Comment: @S.D. check my final answer... mark as correct and useful if you are happy

Comment: The use of `SizedBox`  causes problems because with a fixed width of `width: 1000.0,`, there is lots of white space if the list uses < 1000px

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? (Lots of extra white space)